# Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp' while reading xml from URL in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.XmlResolver = null;

    xmldoc.Load("URL");
    XmlWriter xmlWrite = XmlWriter.Create(@Server.MapPath("Test.xml"));
    xmldoc.Save(xmlWrite);
    xmlWrite.Close();
```

Above is the code I am using  to read an XML file.  The XML I am loading contains entities like `nbsp;` and because of that, the code is throwing an XMLException:

> *Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'*

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this, but for both you need to **make changes to the input file.**

1) Change your `&nbsp;` to `&#160;` in you input files. It is always better to use Unicode and avoid readable entities in XML documents. Use plain Unicode characters or their numerical form.

2) If you still need/want to use `&nbsp;` 
You can declare a custom doctype in the file that will do the conversion for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE doctypeName [
   <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
```

This problem is coming because `&nbsp;` isn't one of XMLs predefined entities.

Comment: When one wants to _output_ a file with actual &nbsp; in it in C# and re-read it, one has to use `xmlDoc.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateDocumentType("xyzdoc", null, null, "<!ENTITY nbsp '&amp;' >"));` in output (expand string to set up more entities)

Answer (score 8):

I had this same problem today, and I was able to solve it by **changing the HTML entity name to an HTML entity number**.

Per [this helpful forum post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1219076.aspx/1), I was able to fix this error.

HTML entity names are not well supported in XML. This is why the "nonbreaking space"--"nbsp"--triggers this frustrating error.

The easiest way to fix this issue is to use HTML entity numbers, which means changing `&nbsp;` to `&#160;`.

For a comprehensive listing of HTML entities with names and numbers, see:

[W3 School's HTML Entity reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

[Official W3C Page on Entity Sets](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#h-A2).

Comment: And it didn't occur to you that **HTML** named entities might be a **HTML** thing and thus have no relevance to **XML**? ;-)

Comment: Sure, but the trouble is I'm working within a web app that a different team built, and my options are severely limited. They constructed a system that toggles between HTML and XML for whatever reason. So, I adapted. *shrug*

Comment: Please do not use W3 School for reference - this is not official source. Instead use official source for entities: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#h-A2

Comment: Thanks, Dima. I've updated my answer to include the W3C link. I think that the W3Schools link is still useful, so I kept it intact.

Answer (score 0):

Late to this, but you can also replace `&nbsp` with `&amp;nbsp;` if you don't want to remember what `&#160;` means.

Comment: That changes the meaning of the text, unlike changing to &#160;