# System.Xml.XmlException: Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm a junior developper ASP.Net and I have error : 
“Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 69, position 41.”

I have 2 fonctions almost the sames :

```
  public async Task<IEnumerable<ContactEcocert>> GetContactsEcocertAsync(Guid entityId)
            {
                RestRequest request = new RestRequest { Resource = "Entity/{entityId}/MyContactsEcocert" };
                request.AddParameter("entityId", entityId, ParameterType.UrlSegment);

                return await RestHelper.ExecuteAsync<List<ContactEcocert>>(request);
            }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ContactEcocertSubsidiary>> GetContactSubsidiariesByEntityAsync(Guid entityId)
        {
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest { Resource = "Entity/{entityId}/contactSubsidiary" };
            request.AddParameter("entityId", entityId, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            try
            {
                return await RestHelper.ExecuteAsync<List<ContactEcocertSubsidiary>>(request);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.TraceError($"Erreur lors de la récupèration des filiales lié a l'entitée courante  {entityId} : {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

and the 2nd one done this error :

```
“Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 69, position 41.”
```

I have no idea where I can find this line 69, position 41, and when I'm looking for 'nbsp' with Ctrl+F I can not find it anywhere in my code.

error appears in the line :

```
return await RestHelper.ExecuteAsync<List<ContactEcocertSubsidiary>>(request);
```

I would like to check my file xml but I don't know how?
Any ideas where I can search ?

Comment: nbsp is usually a &nbsp; symbol for a non breaking space. have a look at encoding the string in UTF8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp' while reading xml from URL in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701745/reference-to-undeclared-entity-nbsp-while-reading-xml-from-url-in-c)

Comment: Fuzzybear : how/where can I find this encoding please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nbsp; and other html entities are listed here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp
This should be a correct answer to your question.

Comment: But I'm not using a &nsbp anywhere... so how it's possible this error?

Comment: Probably came from request.AddParameter("entityId", entityId, ParameterType.UrlSegment); sure you are not changing entityId before calling the other function?

Comment: Wow, I just changed entityId in Id (It was like that before but I was sure it will change nothing... ) Thank you a lot :)

Comment: and can you explain me why this change was good?  After all, it is not important the name of variable ? In my Controller I'm passing in parameter "id" but for the previous function uit's the same (i'm passing id  and I'm receving Guid entityId : public async Task<IEnumerable<ContactEcocert>> GetContactsEcocertAsync(Guid entityId) ...

Comment: Controller code :  public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            Guid id = HttpContext.GetCurrentEntity();   //5272af6a-3ef4-486d-8659-c069f45bf3c1
            IEnumerable<ContactEcocert> contactEcocert = (await _clientService.GetContactsEcocertAsync(id)).ToList();
            IEnumerable<ContactEcocertSubsidiary> contactEcocertSubsidiary = (await _clientService.GetContactSubsidiariesByEntityAsync(id)).ToList();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176805/discussion-between-matj-stagl-and-elzbieta-igual).